# Can't create a BIN FIle in forms application using BinaryWriter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, bin

I am having an issue that is perplexing me.  I used the follow lines of codes in a simple Console app that produces a correctly formatted BIN File shown below.  When I moved this code into my Forms Application, into an event handler, it now produces a BIN file that is very incorrect.

The code is identical in both programs I have debugged through the forms application and it sends the correct bytes to the BinaryWriter.  However, a bad result is produced when in the Forms Application.
Does anyone know why this would produce a bad result.

```
string datastream = strStreamData;
string[] DataStream_Array = datastream.Split(' ');
string[] RawData = new string[DataStream_Array.Length - 21];

for (int index = 0; index < DataStream_Array.Length - 21; index++)
{
    RawData[index] = DataStream_Array[index + 20];
}

using (BinaryWriter bin = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("MyBiN.bin", FileMode.Create)))
{
    foreach (string data in RawData)
    {
        byte databyte = Convert.ToByte(data, 16);
        bin.Write(databyte); 
    }
}
```

Is there a problem using an event handler with this code inside?

This is the correctly formmated BIN file from the Console Application
[image]

This is the result from my Forms App from inside the event handler
[image]

Comment: The input on `strStreamData` is the same? Where/how does that get filled?

Comment: that string comes from the event handler, when debugging I have checked it and it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Just to be sure: `Console.App.strStreamData == Forms.App.strStreamData`?

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure that is not the problem.

Comment: Can you post the first value of data and databyte?